# What is the difference between `dyn` and generics?

Tags: rust

I'm reading some code and it has a `consume` function which makes it possible for me to pass my own function `f`.

```rust
fn consume<R, F>(self, _timestamp: Instant, len: usize, f: F) -> Result<R>
    where
        F: FnOnce(&mut [u8]) -> Result<R>,
```

I wrote some similar code, but like this:

```rust
pub fn phy_receive(
        &mut self,
        f: &mut dyn FnMut(&[u8])
    ) -> u8 {
```

and to be fair I don't know what is the difference, aside from `FnOnce` vs `FnMut`. What is the difference between using `dyn` vs a generic type parameter to specify this function?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/whats-the-difference-between-t-trait-and-dyn-trait/35381/3

Answer (score 21):

Using `dyn` with types results in dynamic dispatch (hence the `dyn` keyword), whereas using a (constrained) generic parameter results in monomorphism.

### General explanation

#### Dynamic dispatch

Dynamic dispatch means that a method call is resolved at runtime. It is generally more expensive in terms of runtime resources than monomorphism.

For example, say you have the following trait

```
trait MyTrait {
  fn f(&self);
  fn g(&self);
}
```

and a struct `MyStruct` which implements that trait. If you use a `dyn` reference to that trait (e.g. `&dyn MyTrait`), and pass a reference to a `MyStruct` object to it, what happens is the following:

- A "vtable" data structure is created. This is a table containing pointers to the `MyStruct` implementations of `f` and `g`.
- A pointer to this vtable is stored with the `&dyn MyTrait` reference, hence the reference will be twice its usual size; sometimes `&dyn` references are called "fat references" for this reason.
- Calling `f` and `g` will then result in indirect function calls using the pointers stored in the vtable.

#### Monomorphism

Monomorphism means that the code is generated at compile-time. It's similar to copy and paste. Using `MyTrait` and `MyStruct` defined in the previous section, imagine you have a function like the following:

```
fn sample<T: MyTrait>(t: T) { ... }
```

And you pass a `MyStruct` to it:

```
sample(MyStruct);
```

What happens is the following:

- During compile time, a copy of the `sample` function is created specifically for the `MyStruct` type. In very simple terms, this is as if you copied and pasted the `sample` function definition and replaced `T` with `MyStruct`:

```
fn sample__MyStruct(t: MyStruct) { ... }
```

- The `sample(MyStruct)` call gets compiled into `sample__MyStruct(MyStruct)`.

This means that in general, monomorphism can be more expensive in terms of binary code size (since you are essentially duplicating similar chunks of code, but for different types), but there's no runtime cost like there is with dynamic dispatch.

Monomorphism is also generally more expensive in terms of compile times: because it essentially does copy-paste of code, codebases that use monomorphism abundantly tend to compile a bit slower.

### Your example

Since `FnMut` is just a trait, the above discussion applies directly to your question. Here's the trait definition:

```
pub trait FnMut<Args>: FnOnce<Args> {
    pub extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
}
```

Disregarding the `extern "rust-call"` weirdness, this is a trait just like `MyTrait` above. This trait is implemented by certain Rust functions, so any of those functions is analogous to `MyStruct` from above. Using `&dyn FnMut<...>` will result in dynamic dispatch, and using `<T: FnMut<...>>` will result in monomorphism.

### My 2 cents and general advice

Certain situations will require you to use a dynamic dispatch. For example, if you have a `Vec` of external objects implementing a certain trait, you have no choice but to use dynamic dispatch. For example,
`Vec<Box<dyn Debug>>`. If those objects are internal to your code, though, you could use an `enum` type and monomorphism.

If your trait contains an associated type or a generic method, you will have to use monomorphism, because such traits are not [object safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety).

Everything else being equal, my advice is to pick one preference and stick with it in your codebase. From what I've seen, most people tend to prefer defaulting to generics and monomorphism.

Comment: Nice answer! You definitely covered this, but I would like to stress that using `f: &mut dyn FnMut` causes *calls to `f`* to be dispatched dynamically, but using generics causes *calls to `sample`* to be monomorphized. So in a sense using generics lets you "push" the choice of dispatch into the caller of `sample` (all the more evident here since `&mut dyn FnMut` itself implements `FnMut`, so even the generic version can still use dynamic dispatch, at the caller's discretion).

Comment: I don't think this answer is helpful. The first part explains how they are implemented internally, which is not a big concern from a programmer's POV; the 2nd part explains in what situations should we use which of them, but only stated the conclusion without explaining the reason. It doesn't clear up my confusion at all.