# Polymorphism with associated types

Tags: rust

With plain traits, this is possible:

```
trait TestTrait {
    fn show(&self);
}

fn call_show(t: &dyn TestTrait) {
    t.show()
}
```

But not with associated types:

```
trait TestTrait {
    type Item: std::fmt::Display;
    
    fn show(&self);
}

fn call_show(t: &dyn TestTrait) {
    t.show()
}
```

Sure, all implementations with a specific type for `Item` would work. But it is not possible to "wild card" `Item`, like (`<Item = _>`). Is there some other way to achieve this?

Comment: Doesn't a generic `fn` do the job?
`fn call_show<T: TestTrait>(t: T) { t.show() }`

Comment: It does, but it is monomorphism: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66575869/what-is-the-difference-between-dyn-and-generics. From that thread, looks like polymorphism is not possible with associated types.

Comment: What about combining supertraits with default impl + monomorphism of a single generic to achieve polymorphism?

```trait SuperTrait: TestTrait + AnotherTestTrait {
      fn show() { self.show_impl() };
      fn show_impl();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, `call_show` just has to be generic over the associated type:

```rust
trait TestTrait {
    type Item: std::fmt::Display;
    
    fn show(&self);
}

fn call_show<Item: std::fmt::Display>(t: &dyn TestTrait<Item = Item>) {
    t.show()
}
```

But since `TestTrait<Item = A>` and `TestTrait<Item = B>` require different vtables, (they are essentially different traits) there is no way for a single (non generic) function to handle them both.

Comment: Thanks. Given this is possible:
`
trait TestTrait<Item> {
    fn show(&self);
}
fn call_show<T: std::fmt::Display>(t: &dyn TestTrait<T>) {
    t.show()
}
`

This is a difference in behavior, for generics vs associated types. The vtable detail appears to be more like an implementation artifact, something that ought not to be leaked in the observed behavior.

Comment: That's the exact same behavior, you fix the generic in your example or the associated type in the answer to a type parameter of the function, that way you get one monomorphized function per type/trait.

Comment: Sorry my example was bit off. What I want is something like a builder pattern: `fn build() -> Box<dyn TestTrait> {..}`. Based on some condition, it would return an implementor of the trait, with possibly different instances of Item(which the caller does not know in advance or cares about). Looks like this would not be possible with associated types

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your `TestTrait` into two traits. Something like that:

```rust
trait TestTrait {
    fn show(&self);
}

trait TestTraitItem: TestTrait {
    type Item: std::fmt::Display;
}
```

Now you can create `dyn TestTrait` without problems and still may have concrete type for `Item` when it's needed.

Comment: This works in this case, but only if the associated type is not used in the trait.

Comment: Every method, that requires concrete `Item` type, must be defined in `TestTraitItem`. Other methods may be defined in `TestTrait`.
If you run into situation, where you need a conrete `Item` type in `TestTrait`, then it's a good signal that you need totally rethink your architecture.