# Does exists a way to pass generic arguments at runtime?

Tags: generics, rust, macros, metaprogramming

I mean, I have a function that receives a serialized argument, then internally de-serializes it into `T` and calls to another function with `T` argument de-serialized.

Something like this.

```rust
// Args Struct: T target for de-serialize argument
struct InnerArgs {
    //...
    //fields
    //...
}

// outer function
fn outer(args: &[u8]) -> Result<(), ()> {
    // this is the line for de-serialize
    let args = serde::deserialized::<InnerArgs>(args).unwrap();

    inner(args)
}

// inner function
fn inner(args: InnerArgs) -> Result<(), ()> {
    ///whatever thing
}
```

I'm generating all this stuff with macros from info about a function signature from a trait.

This works well, but...

I want to support generic types for `Args Struct` like this:

```rust
// T target but with generics
struct InnerArgs<U> { 
    t: U
    //whatever fields
    //...
}

// outer function but I can't change the signature :(
fn outer(args: &[u8]) -> Result<(), ()> {
    // this is the line for deserialize
    let args = serde::deserialized::<InnerArgs>(args).unwrap();

    inner(args)
}

// inner function now with U generic
fn inner<U>(args: InnerArgs<U>) -> Result<(), ()> {
    ///whatever thing
}
```

But I can't change the signature for the `outer function`, it means I have no knowledge about the generics when I'm inside the function for de-serialize argument.

But I can play with the structure of the arguments, because is a `"Request"` and I can for example modify it to de-serialize it in several steps.

And here is my doubt - Exist any way to calculate the generic parameter and pass it at runtime?

Is it possible to pass some kind of meta-information about the generic maybe with [`syn`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/) or something else to achieve this?

Comment: There are two ways to support "generic" types at runtime: `enum` or `Box<dyn Trait>`. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66597209/5397009) for an explanation of the differences and tradeoffs.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28219519/5397009

Comment: Thanks, I am writing a small RPC protocol, what I wanted was to be able to define RPC interfaces with generics, but something complicated because at the time of serializing to send the request the information of the generics is lost. I think I will have to discard it, at least for now.